# XSLT: XPath comparison between two files

Tags: xslt, file-comparison

I would like to compare two XML-files via XSLT. The comparison should be considered to be successful if all elements of a specific type in document 1 are located at the same XPath position in document 2.

Consider

```
<entry>
    <entry1>
        <entry2>
            <value type="1"/>
        </entry2>
    </entry1>
</entry>
```

as document 1.

The element under observation is "value" (with attribute type=1) which is located at entry/entry1/entry2. Therefore a comparison in this sense to

```
<entry>
    <entry0/>
    <entry0/>
    <entry1>
        <entry2>
            <value type="1"/>
        </entry2>
    </entry1>
</entry>
```

should be considered as successful, while

```
<entry>
    <entry1>
        <value type="1"/>
    </entry1>
</entry>
```

is not successful, since "value" (with attribute type=1) is located at entry/entry1. Also
the comparison to

```
<entry>
    <entry1>
        <entry2>
            <value type="2"/>
        </entry2>
    </entry1>
</entry>
```

should be considered as not successful since the attribute of value is type=2.

My naive trial to fulfill this task in XSLT was something like:

```
<xsl:template match="value">
   <xsl:if test="not(document($doc2)/.[@type=@type])">
      <xsl:text>something is missing</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This approach wasn't successful because the selection of the desired XPath within the 2nd document seems not to work.

Maybe you have an idea on how to address this question?

Matt

Comment: If you need to test only a few elements probably the best way is to write testing XPaths by hand, execute them against different files and compare results. Otherwise I don't know simple solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your comparison. `<entry><entry1><entry2><value type="1"/></entry2></entry1></entry> ` is very different from `entry><entry0/><entry0/><entry1><entry2><value type="1"/></entry2></entry1>` . Why should the comparison between them be successful?

Comment: Ok, don't call it "comparison" but "check, whether every element under observation in doc1 is present in doc2 at the same XPath". I'm going to try deep-equal as proposed in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, an XSLT 1.0 translation of Dr. Kay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259940/xslt-xpath-comparison-between-two-files/5260858#5260858):

```
    <xsl:variable name="vTest1">
        <xsl:for-each select="$D1//value[@type]">
            <xsl:variable name="vPath1">
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="vTest2">
                <xsl:for-each select="$D2//value[@type=current()/@type]">
                    <xsl:variable name="vPath2">
                        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="$vPath1=$vPath2">True</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$vTest2=''">False</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Then `$vTest1 = ''` would be the boolean value of the test.

Comment: thanks a lot, the solution is almost 1:1 applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is hopelessly underspecified. For example, as well as requiring every element in doc1 to have a corresponding element in doc2, do you also require every element in doc2 to have a corresponding element in doc1?

However, something close might be the condition *"for every element `V1` in `D1` such that `name(V1)=N`, there exists an element `V2` in `D2` such that `name(V2)=N and deep-equal(V1, V2) and path(V1) = path(V2)`, where path($V) is defined as `string-join($V/ancestor-or-self::*/name())`"*, Which translates into the following XPath 2.0 expression:

```
every $V1 in $D1//N satisfies
some $V2 in $D2//N satisfies
deep-equal($V1, $V2) and
string-join($V1/ancestor-or-self::*/name())
 = string-join($V2/ancestor-or-self::*/name())
```

Comment: Sorry if you think my question is underspecified, I just tried to focus on the main aspect. And especially your example is not relevant: doc2 may include tons of other elements that won't affect the comparison in my sense (so may be the word "comparison" is misleading - sorry for that!) Anyway, thank you for the idea which indeed is helpful.